# Spring Reactor onErrorContinue not working

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux

As per [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#onErrorContinue-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) I am expecting `onErrorContinue` will ignore the error element and continue the sequence. Below test case is failing with exception

> java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNext(12)" failed (expected: onNext(12); actual: onError(java.lang.RuntimeException:

```
@Test
public void testOnErrorContinue() throws InterruptedException {
    Flux<Integer> fluxFromJust = Flux.just(1, 2,3,4,5)
            .concatWith(Flux.error(new RuntimeException("Test")))
            .concatWith(Flux.just(6))
            .map(i->i*2)
            .onErrorContinue((e,i)->{
                System.out.println("Error For Item +" + i );
            })
            ;
    StepVerifier
            .create(fluxFromJust)
            .expectNext(2, 4,6,8,10)
            .expectNext(12)
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`onErrorContinue()` may not be doing what you think it does - it lets upstream operators *recover* from errors that may occur within them, if they happen to support doing so. It's a rather specialist operator.

In this case `map()` does actually support `onErrorContinue`, but map isn't actually producing an error - the error has been inserted into the stream already (by way of `concat()` and the explicit `Flux.error()` call.) In other words, there's no operator producing the error at all, so there's therefore nothing for it to recover from, as an element supplied is erroneous.

If you changed your stream so that `map()` actually *caused* the error, then it would work as expected:

```
Flux.just(1, 2,3,4,5)
        .map(x -> {
            if(x==5) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            return x*2;
        })
        .onErrorContinue((e,i)->{
            System.out.println("Error For Item +" + i );
        })
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Produces:

```
2
4
6
8
Error For Item +5
```

An alternative depending on the real-world use case may be to use `onErrorResume()` after the element (or element source) that may be erroneous:

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        .concatWith(Flux.error(new RuntimeException()))
        .onErrorResume(e -> {
            System.out.println("Error " + e + ", ignoring");
            return Mono.empty();
        })
        .concatWith(Flux.just(6))
        .map(i -> i * 2)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

In general, using another "onError" operator (such as `onErrorResume()`) is generally the more usual, and more recommended approach, since `onErrorContinue()` is dependent on operator support and affects upstream, not downstream operators (which is unusual.)