# WebFlux: onErrorContinue does not continue

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have the following flux:

```
Flux.generate(() -> 1, (n, sink) -> {
            if(n==10){
                sink.complete();
            }
            if(n==2) throw new RuntimeException("some error");
            sink.next(n);
            return n+1;
        })
        .onErrorContinue(
                RuntimeException.class,
                (e, o) -> System.out.println("ERROR")
        )
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I want to get an output as `1, "ERROR", 3, 4 ...`, but instead of that I'm not able to continue, and the flux only executes 1 and terminates with

> [ERROR] (main) Operator called default onErrorDropped -
> reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: some error

Does anyone know how to skip these error signals and continue the flux execution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Reactor onErrorContinue not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521702/spring-reactor-onerrorcontinue-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you cannot throw an exception to the Flux::generate code.

```
Flux.<Integer, Integer>generate(() -> 1, (n, sink) -> {
            if (n == 10) {
                sink.complete();
            }
            sink.next(n);
            return n + 1;
        })
        .doOnNext(n -> {
            if (n == 2) throw new RuntimeException("some error");
        })
        .onErrorContinue(
                RuntimeException.class,
                (e, o) -> System.out.println("ERROR")
        )
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

`onErrorContinue()` is a very special operator that is supported on specific operators only.

Check [Reactor documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#onErrorContinue-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) for details

> Note that onErrorContinue() is a specialist operator that can make the
> behaviour of your reactive chain unclear. It operates on upstream, not
> downstream operators, it requires specific operator support to work,
> and the scope can easily propagate upstream into library code that
> didn't anticipate it (resulting in unintended behaviour.)

In most cases better to use `onErrorResume()` and return `Mono.empty()` for similar behavior.

```
Flux.<Integer, Integer>generate(() -> 1, (n, sink) -> {
        if (n == 10) {
            sink.complete();
        }
        sink.next(n);
        return n + 1;
    })
    .doOnNext(n -> {
        if (n == 2) throw new RuntimeException("some error");
    })
    .onErrorResume(RuntimeException.class, e -> {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        return Mono.empty();
    })
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```